# Why isn't Bundle Install running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So admittedly this is partly my fault. This all started because I wanted to install bootstrap. I fell down a rabbit hole, because it initially wasn't working, so now I keep getting these errors in my console.

All I'm trying to do right now is run 'bundle install'. It worked fine about fifteen minutes prior, and now I'm receiving this message:

```
    current directory: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/pg-1.1.4/ext
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby -I /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200613-11040-1x5o4mg.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-pg
        --without-pg
        --enable-windows-cross
        --disable-windows-cross
        --with-pg-config
        --without-pg-config
        --with-pg_config
        --without-pg_config
        --with-pg-dir
        --without-pg-dir
        --with-pg-include
        --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
        --with-pg-lib
        --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/pg-1.1.4/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/pg-1.1.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/pg-1.1.4/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (1.1.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '1.1.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  pg
```

so then I check the file the error directs me to ( the mkmf.log ), and I receive this:

```
--------------------

find_header: checking for libpq-fe.h... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0/x86_64-linux -I/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/backward -I/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0 -I.    -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wduplicated-cond -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wrestrict -Wwrite-strings -Wimplicit-fallthrough=0 -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wsuggest-attribute=format -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wunused-variable  -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -Wl,-rpath,'/../lib' -Wl,-rpath,'/../lib' -lruby  -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"gcc -E -I/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0/x86_64-linux -I/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/backward -I/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0 -I.    -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wduplicated-cond -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wrestrict -Wwrite-strings -Wimplicit-fallthrough=0 -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wsuggest-attribute=format -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wunused-variable  -fPIC  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:3:10: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
 #include <libpq-fe.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
/* end */

--------------------
```

if it's any help at all, here's my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

gem 'rails',                      '6.0.2.1'
gem 'image_processing',           '1.9.3'
gem 'mini_magick',                '4.9.5'
gem 'active_storage_validations', '0.8.2'
gem 'bcrypt',                     '3.1.13'
gem 'faker',                      '2.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate',              '3.1.8'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate',    '1.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',             '3.4.1'
gem 'puma',                       '3.12.2'
gem 'sass-rails',                 '5.1.0'
gem 'webpacker',                  '4.0.7'
gem 'turbolinks',                 '5.2.0'
gem 'jbuilder',                   '2.9.1'
gem 'bootsnap',                   '1.4.5', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.4.1'
  gem 'byebug',  '11.0.1', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '4.0.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.1.5'
  gem 'spring',                '2.1.0'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara',                 '3.28.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver',       '3.142.4'
  gem 'webdrivers',               '4.1.2'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.4'
  gem 'minitest',                 '5.11.3'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.3.8'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.15.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.6'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',         '1.1.4'
  gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '1.46.0', require: false
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Please help, I'm at the point of tearing my hair out. This is very frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here: https://wikimatze.de/installing-postgresql-gem-under-ubuntu-and-mac/

Try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

then try `bundle install` again.

Answer (score 1):

Ben has given the answer (I think). But you mention bootstrap.

Rails 6 has a new approach to allow you to use node packages in your app. This is “the new way” for using css and js frameworks; instead of the old asset pipeline. The bootstrap gems all try to make it easier to integrate bootstrap into the asset pipeline.

While the old way still works; you might want to invest in learning the new way. Have a look at https://hackernoon.com/integrate-bootstrap-4-and-font-awesome-5-in-rails-6-u87u32zd for some specifics in getting the bootstrap npm package into rails.

Not only does learning this new approach help future proof your development, you’ll also find that once you’ve mastered that approach you will be able to use the much better supported npm packages for your favourite js/css tools; instead of waiting for the gems to be updated (if they exist at all)