# Bundle Exec Rake Test and rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I run **$ bundle exec rake test** and I receive this:

```
ubuntu:~/environment/sample_app (modeling-users) $ bundle exec rake test
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootstrap-4.3.1/lib/bootstrap/version.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant Bootstrap::VERSION
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.4.1/lib/bootstrap-sass/version.rb:2: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootstrap-4.3.1/lib/bootstrap/version.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant Bootstrap::BOOTSTRAP_SHA
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.4.1/lib/bootstrap-sass/version.rb:3: warning: previous definition of BOOTSTRAP_SHA was here
Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

        rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

Okay, great, so I run **$ rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test** and I receive this:

```
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootstrap-4.3.1/lib/bootstrap/version.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant Bootstrap::VERSION
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.4.1/lib/bootstrap-sass/version.rb:2: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootstrap-4.3.1/lib/bootstrap/version.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant Bootstrap::BOOTSTRAP_SHA
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.4.1/lib/bootstrap-sass/version.rb:3: warning: previous definition of BOOTSTRAP_SHA was here
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. Please specify the Rails release the migration was written for:

  class AddPasswordDigestToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:536:in `inherited'
/home/ubuntu/environment/sample_app/db/migrate/20200614082512_add_password_digest_to_users.rb:1:in `<main>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1010:in `load_migration'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1006:in `migration'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1002:in `disable_ddl_transaction'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1368:in `use_transaction?'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1360:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1309:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1281:in `block in migrate_without_lock'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1280:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1280:in `migrate_without_lock'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1231:in `migrate'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1061:in `up'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in `migrate'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:238:in `migrate'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:86:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:84:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:84:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/environment/sample_app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/environment/sample_app/bin/spring:15:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/environment/sample_app/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'

Caused by:
StandardError: Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. Please specify the Rails release the migration was written for:

  class AddPasswordDigestToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:536:in `inherited'
/home/ubuntu/environment/sample_app/db/migrate/20200614082512_add_password_digest_to_users.rb:1:in `<main>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1010:in `load_migration'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1006:in `migration'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1002:in `disable_ddl_transaction'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1368:in `use_transaction?'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1360:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1309:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1281:in `block in migrate_without_lock'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1280:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1280:in `migrate_without_lock'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1231:in `migrate'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1061:in `up'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in `migrate'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:238:in `migrate'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:86:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:84:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:84:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/environment/sample_app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/environment/sample_app/bin/spring:15:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/environment/sample_app/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I **see** some of the errors, but I don't fully understand what it's asking me to do or what these errors mean. I'm extremely new to rails, so apologies if these are more than obvious. This is my literal first time learning any of this, point blank. Thank you!

Comment: Hi. Have you checked your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62370391/rails-aborted-migrate-command

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with bootstrap-sass.

Remove it from your gemfile and run `gem uninstall bootstrap-sass`

That will solve this error; but leave you without bootstrap-sass. But at least you now have a working rails env.

Had you installed 2 separate, conflicting bootstrap gems? Looks like bootstrap is being instanciated twice (that’s the actual error message)

Also, see my comment in your other question for a “better” way to get bootstrap running in rails 6. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62392966/1777331